# Help understanding this Apollo 11 docking probe image, what are we looking at, and from where?

Tags: apollo-program, identify-this-object, apollo-11, mechanisms

The New York Times mix media "article" [Apollo 11
As They Shot It](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/07/18/science/apollo-11-as-they-shot-it-ul.html) shows original photographic images taken by the astronauts and related quotes by them.

In one section the text says:

> **Inspecting the Eagle**
>
> ARMSTRONG: Mike must have done a smooth job in that docking. There isn’t a dent or a mark on the probe.

A montage of images is shown, here's a screen capture but you should go look at the originals for details.

- What am I looking at?
- From what location in what spacecraft was this photo taken from?
- Is the conical thing the command module's nose?
- How did it get inside?
- What is the complicated device with all the blue anodized metal near the bottom of the photo?

[image: Apollo 11 Inspecting the Eagle]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the "probe and drogue". The complicated thing is the probe, the conical thing is the drogue.

[image]

> The docking between the Apollo command and lunar modules employed the
>   use of a "probe and drogue" system. The probe was mounted in the
>   docking tunnel of the command module, while the conical drogue was
>   mounted in the docking tunnel of the lunar module.
>
> The CM would extend its probe and approach the lunar module. The cone
>   of the drogue would guide the command module until it was properly
>   centered, and the capture latches on the tip of the probe would
>   engage, effecting "capture." The probe would then be retracted until
>   the docking tunnels of the two spacecraft met, and the 12 docking
>   latches on the command module would engage the LM's docking tunnel,
>   effecting a "hard dock."
>
> Once hard dock was achieved, the probe was collapsed, removed from the
>   docking tunnel, and stowed. This allowed access to the LM's drogue,
>   which was similarly removed and stowed, allowing access to the LM's
>   pressure hatch.

[Source](http://heroicrelics.org/stafford/apollo-probe-and-drogue/index.html)

[image]

([picture source](https://www.quora.com/How-was-the-docking-probe-in-the-Apollo-Command-Module-CM-removed-so-the-astronauts-can-move-freely-between-the-CM-and-the-Lunar-Module))

As far as where the picture is taken, it appears to be in the lower equipment bay of the Command Module. There's a cool 3D model of the Command Module you can fly through [here](https://3d.si.edu/apollo11cm). I couldn't totally control the eyepoint (could be pilot error) but I got pretty close. I screen-shotted the model and annotated three prominent features with red arrows. Then I pasted in one of the images from the combo shot in the question and annotated the same features with green arrows.

[image]

Comment: "I couldn't totally control the eyepoint (could be pilot error) but I got pretty close."  Drag your mouse in the window to look toward where you want to move your eyeball.  Then *spin your mouse scroll wheel* to move toward or away the point you are currently looking at.  Finally, drag your mouse to turn your eyeball towards your point of interest.  Not a great user interface, but it works.

Comment: @DrSheldon thanks! It was the translational movement that I couldn't find.

Comment: I'll study this today, will take some time. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh take a look at the Smithsonian virtual CM if you get a chance, it's fun.