# What happen to the Smithsonian Institutes 3d scan of the Apollo 11 Command Module?

Tags: apollo-11, command-module

"Since its landing on July 24th, 1969, the Columbia has been kept sealed in plexiglass at the Smithsonian Institute in Washington, DC. That is, until recently, when the software company Autodesk was allowed a rare opportunity to use their high-tech 3D scanning equipment to create a simulation of the spacecraft that anyone on the internet can explore.

Explore the inside of the Columbia and take a guided tour over at the Smithsonian Institute's website."

https://3d.si.edu/apollo11cm/

This link no longer works.  It did at one time.  Does anyone know how I can view this again?

Comment: Good question, but the claim that *Columbia* has been in plexiglass since its landing is dubious.  It completely ignores the month of post-processing and quarantine.  I also find it unlikely (and possibly negligent) that no curator has entered it in 50 years.  Sure, maybe no *outside* party has entered the module in 50 years.

Comment: I linked to it in this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37542/6944 and it does not work there either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the new link by just looking around for a few minutes: [Apollo 11 3D](https://3d.si.edu/object/3d/command-module-apollo-11:d8c63e8a-4ebc-11ea-b77f-2e728ce88125). It was easy.

See also the [hatch](https://3d.si.edu/object/3d/hatch-crew-apollo-11-cad-model:936d1822-b237-4431-bb3f-a1f9d39a2e90).

Comment: That doesn't look like the fly-through simulation I linked to.